# cuckoo-ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shutdown'

Tags: python, cuckoo

I run cuckoo,but it stopped,display like this:
'''
2021-12-09 18:50:38,135 [cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Using "virtualbox" as machine manager
Oops! Cuckoo failed in an unhandled exception!
Sometimes bugs are already fixed in the development release, it is therefore recommended to retry with the latest development release available https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo
If the error persists please open a new issue at https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues

```
=== Exception details ===
Cuckoo version: 2.0.7
OS version: posix
OS release: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Python version: 2.7.12
Python implementation: CPython
Machine arch: i686
Modules: adium-theme-ubuntu:0.3.4 alembic:1.0.10 androguard:3.0.1 argparse:1.2.1 asn1crypto:1.4.0 attrs:21.2.0 beautifulsoup4:4.5.3 bottle:0.12.7 capstone:3.0.5rc2 cffi:1.15.0 chardet:2.3.0 click:6.6 colorama:0.3.7 configparser:4.0.2 contextlib2:0.6.0.post1 cryptography:2.2.1 cuckoo:2.0.7 distorm3:3.5.2 django-extensions:1.6.7 django:1.8.4 dpkt:1.8.7 dumbnet:1.12 ecdsa:0.17.0 egghatch:0.2.3 elasticsearch:5.3.0 enum34:1.1.10 et-xmlfile:1.1.0 flask-sqlalchemy:2.4.0 flask:0.12.2 functools32:3.2.3.post2 future:0.18.2 gevent:1.2.2 greenlet:1.1.2 httpreplay:0.2.6 idna:2.10 importlib-metadata:2.1.2 ipaddress:1.0.23 itsdangerous:1.1.0 jdcal:1.4.1 jinja2:2.9.6 jsbeautifier:1.6.2 jsonschema:4.0.0 libvirt-python:1.3.1 magic-file-extensions:0.2 mako:1.1.6 markupsafe:0.23 olefile:0.43 oletools:0.51 openpyxl:2.2.5 pathlib2:2.3.6 peepdf:0.4.2 pefile2:1.2.11 pefile:1.2.10.post139 pillow:3.2.0 pip:20.3.4 pyasn1:0.4.8 pycparser:2.21 pycrypto:2.6.1 pycurl:7.43.0 pyelftools:0.24 pyguacamole:0.6 pyliblzma:0.5.3 pymisp:2.4.106 pymongo:3.0.3 pyopenssl:18.0.0 pyrsistent:0.16.1 pysqlite:1.0.1 python-dateutil:2.4.2 python-editor:1.0.4 python-magic:0.4.12 python:2.7.12 pythonaes:1.0 pytz:2014.10 requests:2.13.0 roach:0.1.2 rpm-python:4.12.0.1 scandir:1.10.0 scapy:2.3.2 setuptools:20.7.0 sflock:0.3.10 six:1.16.0 sqlalchemy:1.3.3 sqlparse:0.1.18 tlslite-ng:0.6.0 ujson:2.0.3 unicorn:1.0.1 unity-lens-photos:1.0 urlgrabber:3.9.1 urllib3:1.26.7 vboxapi:1.0 volatility:2.6.1 wakeonlan:0.2.2 werkzeug:1.0.1 wheel:0.37.0 wsgiref:0.1.2 yara-python:3.6.3 yum-metadata-parser:1.1.4 zipp:1.2.0

2021-12-09 18:50:38,141 [cuckoo] ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shutdown'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/main.py", line 298, in main
    cuckoo_main(maxcount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/main.py", line 248, in cuckoo_main
    stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/main.py", line 231, in stop
    sched.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/core/scheduler.py", line 945, in stop
    machinery.shutdown()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shutdown'

'''
```

Comment: I have already install python-libvirt 1.3.1

Comment: I did't solve the problem, I reinstall it and error isn't come.

Comment: I think it is because I install virtualbox with a Software installation package,so something is missed.